# Is it possible to view how much bandwidth has been used by a websocket in the google chrome developer tools?

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I am able to view the frames as they come through but I have yet to find a way to see how much data is actually being sent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick. You can use "tshark" to capture the data in/out from web-socket. Or you can use the graphical version of tshark called Wireshark. If you are wanting to print the capture via your progarm (java file) then you can do `Runtime.execute("tshark command here")`. This must be the one way. Web-socket is a TCP socket between server and client. Wireshark can easily to this.